# Windows version of rxvt Backspace key doesn't work as expected

Tags: git, bash, backspace, rxvt

I'm using rxvt.exe, the alternative to bash.exe that comes with msysgit.  My OS is WinXP.

I invoke the console with "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\rxvt.exe" -e /usr/bin/bash --login -i

The backspace key deletes everything backward to the beginning of the line, rather than just one char back.

I've experimented using things like

```
'bind "C-e":backward-delete-char' just to see if I can bind the behavior to a ctrl sequence, and that works, but I can't figure out how to bind with the backspace key.  I've tried binding to e\14 and e\08, but they don't work.
```

An extensive google search turned up plenty of Linux solutions but very little for rxvt on Windows, and nothing that addressed this problem.

Thanks a million to anyone who can provide an answer!

-Jill

Comment: Note that `rxvt.exe` is a [terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator); other similar programs are `xterm`, `wterm`, `aterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `urxvt`. `bash` is a [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)), similar to `ksh`, `csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh`, `ash`, `dash`. The shell is _often_, but not always, used in conjunction with a terminal, but you can usually replace one or the other without troubles.

Comment: Hmm - this shouldn't have been closed - rather moved to serverfault or super user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do I have the solution for you!  Thanks for bringing this up, I've known it was a problem, but never knew how to fix it.  Here you go:

1. Start a git bash shell
2. `cd ~` (your home directory)
3. Create a new file called `.inputrc` and fill it with the following:

   ```
   "\e[3~": delete-char
   # this is actually equivalent to "\C-?": delete-char
   # VT
   "\e[1~": beginning-of-line
   "\e[4~": end-of-line
   # kvt
   "\e[H":beginning-of-line
   "\e[F":end-of-line
   # rxvt and konsole (i.e. the KDE-app...)
   "\e[7~":beginning-of-line
   "\e[8~":end-of-line
   ```
4. Save the file and exit, you should be able to restart with your original command, `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\rxvt.exe" -e /usr/bin/bash --login -i` and use the backspace!

Inspiration for this solution is found [here](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html#Bash).

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response!  The solution worked really well and defined some other keys that I know I'll need!  I also just came across this site:  www.mingw.org/wiki/Configure_RXVT, which recommends adding '-backspacekey ^H' (no quotes) to the command line, which also works.

Comment: Why is this question considered "off topic?" It does "relate to programming or software development in some way." A terminal emulator is a "software tool commonly used by programmers." Also, there are numerous other rxvt-related questions on SO that have not been closed. I'm new to SO so perhaps I've missed something.